# Send JUnit report to specific recipient

Tags: java, maven, junit, jenkins-plugins

I have configured JUnit test suite execution via maven surefire plugin which produces results on nightly bases. After each execution an email is sent to a certain DL where all the submitters are included. But I need to send a mail only to those submitters whose tests are failing. Let's say that person A has written TestA, person B has written TestB. If TestA fails, I know who is responsible for this and I want to send him a notification automatically and not to send such to person B as TestB is OK.

I saw the Jenkins Email-ext+plugin. The problem is that it expects a list with email addresses, which in my case each time is different. If I am able to store the emails after each execution in a file, I could i.e. pass it to a such plugin and it could send mails to the addresses from the file.

Do you know how can I do this magic? :) Maybe I can use the same plugin and put something extra in the templates?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not worth spending time on this.

Comment: I didn't ask if there is a point. I asked for a help finding the correct solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this with the groovyPostbuild plugin combined with the Email-Ext plugin.  Use the groovyPostbuild plugin to dynamically generate the email DL based on the failing unit tests - something like this will give you the class name of the failing test:

```
manager.build.testResultAction?.failedTests?.className
```

Based on that information you can probably use that to compare to the list of files commited (this will depend on which SCM engine you are using).  Once you have the culprits you can generate the email list and export it to a variable.

The Email-Ext plugin can then use that variable to send to the appropriate recipients.

Seems like this would be pretty useful.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Actually I have done this with Maven plugin using the Jenkins API which I am parsing using xpath to the according pattern (i.e. FAILIRES==true). It is pretty good this way and can be integrated in Jenkins via Maven call :)
Thanks! :)